# Handsontable : one double quote is missing after Copy-paste or drag the value (two consecutive double quotes)

Tags: handsontable

Requirement: I have a requirement to use Handsontable on my web application, where the user can enter value with two consecutive double-quotes

jsfiddle link:

```
sample strings: 
${v=""}
var s=""
http://jsfiddle.net/a3uj6/1/
```

Handsontable Issue:
If the cell has Two consecutive double quotes, one double quote is missing upon copy-paste the cell to another cell.
Same issue occurs, if the user drags the cell-value to place it in the next column/cell.

NOTE: User is not doing copy/paste or dragging a multi-line text, it is just a single-line text with two consecutive quotes.

I have posted this as an issue in the github as well. Meanwhile, if there is any work-around to fix the copy/paste issue, is more welcomed.
Thanks.

Comment: github issue is https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/1106 which has been marked as a dupe of https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/379

Answer (score 0):

this is a not elegant solution but is a workaround that works for me.

Using the hook `onBeforePaste` you could handle the contents pasted as follows:

```
onBeforePaste: (values, range) => {
  const { startRow, startCol } = [range];

  var content = [];
  values.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      content.push([startRow + i, startCol + x, value]);
    });
  });
  hotInstante.setDataAtCell(content);

  return false;
},
```

There are the documentation of hooks used

- https://handsontable.com/docs/8.1.0/Core.html#setDataAtCell
- https://handsontable.com/docs/8.1.0/Hooks.html#event:beforePaste